# How do I get the "auto" height of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

So when I set a fixed height on a div with jquery, like `$('div').height(200);`, the value of `$('div').height()` is always 200. Even if the content from that div exceeds that height (I use `overflow:hidden`).

How can I get that true height of the DIV as if it would be in "auto" mode ?

Comment: You mean hidden content height?

Comment: I think it is something to deal with `scrollTop` or `scrollHeight`.

Comment: Vega - yes. The height of the content of the div, including the part that gets hidden by overflow

Comment: @thelolcat Check my answer and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Vega I think you should leave your answer here too. The highest-voted one is probably the best, but yours might be appropriate in some cases.

Comment: @TrevorDixon Undeleted the answer.. hopefully people see it the same way as you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USE

```
.scrollHeight()
```

[element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight)

with jquery try this

```
 $(selector)[0].scrollHeight
```

**DESCRIPTION**

An element's scrollHeight is a measurement of the height of an element's content including content not visible on the screen due to overflow.

**Example**

[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sKZfF/1/) from Vega's Answer

Comment: thanks, though it gets me a slightly larger height than expected, like 10 pixels more..

Comment: it shouldn't if you add `console.log($('div')[0].scrollHeight);` to Vega Demo it will give you the same result as well

Answer (score 3):

> You mean hidden content height?
>
> Vega - yes. The height of the content of the div, including the part that gets hidden by overflow

Just set to `auto` and get the `.height` and set it back to the fixed height.

```
var $el = $('#test');
var tmp = $el.css('height');

var actualHeight = $el.css('height', 'auto').height();

$el.css('height', tmp);
alert(actualHeight);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/sKZfF/

Comment: @MinaGabriel Go ahead and You don't really need to ask.. Good luck.