# jQuery - Scroll to bottom of div on slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to scroll to the bottom of the div when the user clicks on a link to slide the div down.

I've tried using the scrollTo and animate

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

but nothing happens

heres the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/29/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/4/

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.expander').slideToggle();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 1000
    }, 2000);
});
```

Just use your .expander height.

If you need this to be variable you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/26/

```
var scroll_to = $('.expander').offset().top + $('.expander').height();
$('.button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.expander').slideToggle();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scroll_to
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/7/)

USE :

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');
```

**UPDATE**

[Scrolling the div Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/28/)

Use this ,
The trick is in `scrollHeight` see my answer here [How do I get the “auto” height of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133181/how-do-i-get-the-auto-height-of-a-div/18133327#18133327)

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.expander').slideToggle();
  $('.expander ').animate({scrollTop: $('.expander')[0].scrollHeight}, 'slow');
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');
});
```

[Scroll Based on div scroll Height](http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/30/)

Comment: is this gonna scroll to the bottom of the div or just the bottom of the page though?

Comment: the page if you want to scroll the div replace html, body with your div name and pass the div height instead of the document height

Comment: Make sure you set your overflow-y:scroll and you have some stuff in you div too

Comment: ive tried adding in the div class/id but that does not seem to work

Comment: this actually isnt scrolling to the bottom of the div though.....it just scrolls through the content inside the div..i need the page to actually go to the bottom of the DIV

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#something").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top
 }, 1000);
});
```

You are using a class name instead of an id. You must scroll to a unique element.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead.

```
  $('.button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.expander').slideToggle();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 2000);
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/CLzfW/17/

Comment: this goes to the bottom of the browser page though and not the bottom of the div